# Redirect to page and send custom HTTP headers

Tags: php, http, redirect

I use the following code to redirect to a page in PHP. I need to set a custom HTTP headers to pass along with the redirect.

```
header("Location: http://...");
```

How can I archive this?

Comment: Multiple `header` calls.

Comment: I tried adding it before and after the redirect, I then use HttpFox on Firefox but see that the HTTP headers aren't being sent.

Comment: Are you trying to send data with your redirect? Why don't you use php sessions?

Answer (score -19, accepted):

This question needs to be answered differently as depending from where you're looking the answer is different:

### Redirect Response (PHP)

As far as you're concerned about the redirect response (and not the request that may be triggered by a redirect response)

Multiple [`header`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/header) calls:

```
header("Location: ....");
header("Header2: ....");
header("Header3: ....");
...
```

### New Request triggered by a Redirect Response (Browser, HTTP client)

If you're looking for the new request that has been triggered by a redirect response, please consult your HTTP clients technical documentation for your options.

Commonly, HTTP clients do not offer any such options, that is most HTTP clients do not turn response headers into request headers in case one of the response headers is a `Location:` header and a status code in the 3xx range.

This would not make any sense anyway as such practice would be unsafe.

Especially on the level of interactive HTTP clients (like a browser) that automatically perform redirects without approval of the user. See *HTTP*, compare *Fetch API*.

---

Further reading: https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-redirects

Comment: What didn't work for you? Please post your code. I can't guess out of the blue what you're doing wrong.

Comment: header("VIA: maga");
header("X_MSISDN: +27000000000");
header("X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID: +27000000000");
header("Location: url");

Comment: You need to disable automatic redirects in firefox to actually see which response headers are send. If you don't, Firefox will do a second request to the URI given in the `Location` header which is a different thing then. You can disable the automatic redirect temporarly by commenting out the `Location` header or you can disable it by installing a little Add-On: [NoRedirect 1.2.4 Toolpress Strict Edition (Firefox Add-On)](http://toolpress.de/tools/noredirect-1.2.4-fx+sm+toolpress-strict-edition.xpi.html)

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't set custom HTTP headers for a redirect. Never!

Comment: Sounds a bit as if op got puzzled between request and response headers.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, if your response is interpreted by an agent. If you examine the response with a very low-level http client, you may be able to extract the added headers.

Comment: @BretRoyster: Please see this old comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583461/redirect-to-page-and-send-custom-http-headers/7583497?noredirect=1#comment9198044_7583497 --- response headers can be send with any HTTP response, and if the HTTP client creates another request, it's a new thing.

Comment: @hakre - deleted my last comment

Comment: @sepehr: Not _for_ a redirect, and I never wrote that it's possible _for_ a redirect. But it is perfectly technically possible to send other (custom) response headers _and_ the `Location` response header (e.g. `X-Example-....`). The location header represents the redirect to another page, and the other headers _are_ custom headers. This qualifies the _and_ in question title. If that may make no sense is a different judgement apart from properties of the protocol  in use which has been asked for. Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: @hakre: I have no idea what I talked about back then and how these things work anymore  But I trust you have a point there.

Answer (score 147):

I'm afraid, all the answers are wrong and misleading!

It's impossible to redirect to a page with custom headers set, no matter what language or framework you use. In other words, there's no way to trigger an HTTP redirect and cause the client (browser) to add a custom header.

You might be thinking that using multiple `header()` calls should work just fine. But it won't. You're setting the custom headers for the response which is instructing the browser to redirect, not for the redirect itself.

The only way for a site to instruct a browser to issue an HTTP request with a custom header is to use Javascript and the `XMLHttpRequest` object. And it needs CORS implemented on the target server to allow such ajax requests.

Please note that a page can not set HTTP request headers unless it's making an async request using `XMLHttpRequest`. Meaning that you can't do such redirection with the custom header on the client-side as well.

Comment: Is this due to security reasons?

Comment: So ? should the website be a single page application ?

Answer (score -11):

Just add additional `header()` calls after or before this one.

```
header("Location: http://...");
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

Comment: `header("Location: http://...");` will redirect before the second line run.

Comment: it is not possible

Comment: @genesis gone? where?? is everything OK?