# Setting custom request header on a page redirect

Tags: javascript

I have a web application lets call it server1:8080/amcd this application has a setting in it that allows a user to be auto logged in when i pass in a custom request header in the page request. This custom header is called "REMOTE_USER".

My plan is to have another page on another web application, lets call it server2:8080/ssoRedirect/test.html this app on server 2 is acting like a filter where i will pass in a URL parameter such as server2:8080/ssoRedirect/test.html?UserName=user1 this page will take the "user1" parameter and redirect to server1:8080/amcd page while injecting the "user1" value in the "REMOTE_USER" page request.

Any advice in how to I might accomplish this?

I was looking at some simple javascript like below but could not get it to work.

```
<script>

var url = "http://localhost:8080/index.html?userName=user1"; // or window.location.href for current url
var usernameParam = /userName=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1]; 
var result = usernameParam ? usernameParam : 'myDefaultValue';

 function customHeader(remoteinput, userinput) {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("POST", "/log");
    client.setRequestHeader(remoteinput, userinput);

}
    window.location.href = "http://ephesoft.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/dcma/";

</script>
```

I am able to make this work when I use the Modify header plugin for chrome and firefox.

[Image of not request page header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhGXR.png)

Comment: You cannot set custom headers if you are redirecting the user to a different page. `XMLHttpRequest` plays no part in redirection.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to have one server proxy for another server; rather than redirecting, you'd have server1 perform the request with server2 with the header, then return the response from server2.

Comment: So could I write a Java servlet and use that as a proxy? I Could not find a way to redirect on a servlet

Answer (score 21):

A web page can not set HTTP request headers unless you are making an async request using XMLHttpRequest. In this case you are not, you are doing a redirect, like clicking on an href. Instead of relying on custom headers, depending on your backend use any one of these:

1. Cookies
2. GET variables
3. POST variables

Comment: This is correct. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583461/redirect-to-page-and-send-custom-http-headers/41218304#41218304