# How to use javascript to append the header of request before loading that page

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, model-view-controller, get

I have 2 html files belong to two different controllers

This is belong to Index action of SignupController

Index.html

```
<div class="signup-small-font pull-right"><a href="/Account/ResetPassword">Forgot password?</a></div>
```

When click at this link , it will go to that url and make a request to get the view of the ResetPassword Action of AccountController and get the resetPAssword.html

Now what i want is before making that request , i need to append a custom header in the request for the server side .
I was using ajax javascript :

```
function appendHeader(urlCulture){

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlCulture,
    headers: {
        "Culture": 'zh'
    },

})
}
```

What should i do in the index.html anchor link to call this function before requesting for the resetPassword.html

Like what I want is when I click at it , it will navigate to Account/Resetpassword and use the response getting from javascript file to render instead of a normal response

Answer (score 1):

In your html file

```
<div class="signup-small-font pull-right"><a onclick="appendHeader(urlCulture)" href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
```

In your js

```
function appendHeader(urlCulture){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: urlCulture,
        headers: {
            "Culture": 'zh'
        },
        success: function(res) {
            window.location = 'Account/ResetPassword';
        }

    })
}
```

Give it a try. Im not quite sure if this is what you want to do.

Comment: it was saying 'window.location is not a function '

Comment: It should be window.location = "Account/ResetPassword";

Comment: I have change to the correct location, but the problem now is the AccountController get called twice, once with the custom header, and after that it call once without it

Comment: Did you change the value of the href to "#"?

Comment: yes i already did that , but it seems that by setting the window.location to Account/ResetPassword in success , makes it trigger the Action in the account controller again

Answer (score 1):

you are using routes, you need to get the url from the javascript function

there is an example of that here:
[Get local href value from anchor (a) tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439853/get-local-href-value-from-anchor-a-tag)

you could make something similar:

```
<div class="signup-small-font pull-right"><a onclick="return appendCustomHeader(this);" href="/Account/ResetPassword">Forgot password?</a></div>
```

in your js function like the previous reply you could make something like this:

```
function appendCustomHeader(element){

    var url = element.href; // to get full url 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url, 
        headers: {
            "CustomHeader": 'YourCustomHeader'
        },
        success: function(res) {
            // here you make anything else with your response
        }
    })

   return false;
}
```

I've not tested it, I hope it works for you.

it seems you can disable href redirecttion returning false,

see this:

[How can I disable HREF if onclick is executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622100/how-can-i-disable-href-if-onclick-is-executed)

Comment: Hi, this approach somehow also send the request twice, once with the header , and once without it

Comment: Then "href" is working, that is the request without header. Try using a different attribute name instead "href", I've edited the answer. please see it.

Comment: If i change to route , it no longer navigate to that page. Like what I want is when I click at it , it will navigate to Account/Resetpassword and use the response getting from javascript file to render instead of a normal response

Comment: I've edited. return false to disable href redirection, try it.

Comment: putting return false wont navigate to that page even though I still get the correct response. This is not what i want . So the idea is I need to navigate to that page, but it will render the page with the response got from the javascript file

Comment: there is an answer for that, see it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236874/setting-custom-request-header-on-a-page-redirect
it seems that you can't edit header on a redirect, instead try using a form and send the variables by post fields.

Comment: Oops, so that's mean there is no way to accomplish this