# How to send token in header when redirect to external url in react js?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, http-headers, token

in one page i need to after click my url redirect to external Link and i send token in header to this Link, i write redirect with window.location but i dont know how to send token in header

```
  handleModalContinue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = "http://something.com"

    };
```

Comment: It's not possible to send headers when redirecting to another page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236874/setting-custom-request-header-on-a-page-redirect