# Symfony RedirectResponse delete my custom headers headers

Tags: symfony

I am doing a symfony application an I have this return in a route.

```
$response = new RedirectResponse($url, 302);

$response->headers->set(
    'Authorization', 'JWT ' . $this->jwt );

return $response;
```

The problem is that when I launch this code at the browser I don't have the Authorization header in the response.

If I launch with curl in the same route found, I recibe the header. I don't now the reason.

Comment: Did you try something like that:

`
$response = new RedirectResponse($url, 302, $headers = array(
     'Authorization' => 'JWT ' . $this->jwt
));

return $response;
`

Comment: Yes and don't found, the headers never sends in redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom headers cannot be sent with a redirect, see [Redirect to page and send custom HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583461/redirect-to-page-and-send-custom-http-headers/41218304#41218304) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't solved the problem but I use the cookies for send the jwt