# How to redirect to external web page in graphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, next.js

I am working with  Node js and Front-end on Next JS, I have a grahphQL serve with GetUrl method, this method returns a link (example: "https://some-line.com") and I want to redirect a client which made a request to that page with Basic Auth Header, As far as I know In graphql server it is impossible to make a redirect, I have tried to solve this issue on front With React-router package, I made this (Router.push("https://some-line.com) It works but, how to set header?

Comment: I don't know about graphQL but it's impossible with react you will have to use vanilla js check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583461/redirect-to-page-and-send-custom-http-headers/41218304#41218304

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` to redirect. But its impossible in any framework to set a customer header before redirecting. You might want to redesign your logic.