# php redirect to another page and capture body parameters and send as headers

Tags: javascript, php

I am learning php, I want to create a page users can send a post response, redirect to another page and pass the token i get from a service in the body to a header to the redirect site.

I understand that i can redirect via `header("Location: http://www.example.com/");` , how do i capture a body parameter of the form `Token blahblah` and then pass it as a header `Bearer blahblah`

So far i have

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $headers = $_POST['token'];

    if ($headers) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    } 
}
?>
```

I am ok with adding javascript because it seems like its not possible to send custom headers with redirect in php - [Redirect to page and send custom HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583461/redirect-to-page-and-send-custom-http-headers)

Comment: You cannot redirect someone to another page and then take data from that page if its not yours. When you send a header (here Location) you dont redirect the user to a page. You send an instruction to the browser to do so, and every standard compilant browser will follow it (but is not forced to). If you want to receive a token to authorize/authenticate for an api you normally use something like [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php) to communicate with that api and pass the credentials.

Comment: That page is indeed mine.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what you want to do? Redirect to a page and take a token back and somehow use javascript is not much information.

Comment: so i am using a service that sends a token in body and i need to capture that token and send it to another service that expects it in the headers, so I thought I would write a small proxy page that would capture this token from body and send to a header

Comment: Then just put it in your form and submit it.

Comment: Just proxy the request in your post request using curl. The Guzzle client library can make this very easy.  In your post endpoint, you will create a new request with the data from the body in a header location.  You are just applying the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to a http request.

Comment: Thanks, i don't have any control over the two services, but i am just trying to intercept the response and copy the token from body to headers to make them happy

Answer (score -1):

If you want send additional header, you can use `header()` function for token too.
Like so:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $headers = $_POST['token'];

    if ($headers) {
        // your additional header
        header('Bearer: blahblah');

        header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    } 
}
?>
```