# Redirect in Flask - pass a custom header in the request to target

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, flask, http-headers

**TLDR;** How do I set a custom HTTP **request** header in redirect?

Below code redirects to an external service but fails to pass 'Authorization' request header to target. I can see the header in response before redirect happens - can it be forwarded somehow?

```
@app.route('/external_page')
def external_page():
    if not request.cookies.get('id_token'):
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('login',_external=True,_scheme=SCHEME))

    response = flask.redirect(flask.url_for('https://external_service_url/v1/ui'))
    response.headers['Authorization'] = 'token_id'
    return response
```

**Answer:** 
It's not possible, in HTTP and not in any framework.

> The only way for a site to instruct a browser to issue an HTTP request
>   with a custom header is to use Javascript and the XMLHttpRequest
>   object. And it needs CORS implemented on the target server to allow
>   such ajax requests.

Source: [Redirect to page and send custom HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583461/redirect-to-page-and-send-custom-http-headers/41218304[stackoverflow][1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible

See [Redirect to page and send custom HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583461/redirect-to-page-and-send-custom-http-headers/41218304)

> The only way for a site to instruct a browser to issue an HTTP request
>   with a custom header is to use Javascript and the XMLHttpRequest
>   object. And it needs CORS implemented on the target server to allow
>   such ajax requests.